# CSS3 navigation bar top menu

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want to create navigation menu like http://oi61.tinypic.com/345g7wz.jpg

But I found some problems. The li background-color doesn't connected and it display differently in IE

This is my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HdzIf

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="cupcakes.html">Cupcakes</a></li>
                <li class="empty"></li>
                <li><a href="how-to-order.html">How to Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
    margin: 60px 0 40px;
}
.logo {
    height: 162px;
    width: 162px;
    background-color: #9BD1AF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -81px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
    -moz-border-radius: 80px;
    border-radius: 80px;
}
.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    top: 6px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #7E5A3A;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    background: #2D4C4E;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li.empty {
    padding: 10px 59px;
}
nav ul li a {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    color: #F9EEC6;
    background: #2D4C4E;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #7E5A3A;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I found new problem again when I post the code at http://jsfiddle.net/g8SsP/
the logo not in place like I want when the size of the browser is narrowed

Comment: Please post your code to Stackoverflow, in case the codepen site goes down.

Comment: the code already added, sorry in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.logo {
height: 162px;
width: 162px;
background-color: #9BD1AF;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -81px;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-border-radius: 80px;
-moz-border-radius: 80px;
border-radius: 80px;
}
```

change it to this:

```
.logo {
height: 162px;
width: 162px;
background-color: #9BD1AF;
position: relative;
top:68px;
left: 48%;
margin-left: -81px;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-border-radius: 80px;
-moz-border-radius: 80px;
border-radius: 80px;
}
```

the above is for the logo being in place all the time!
and now for the space between the list items to disappear:

```
nav ul li {
display: inline;
background: #2D4C4E;
padding: 10px 20px;
margin-right:-7px; 
}
```

putting a negative margin-right soves the problem.

Comment: thanks it works, but I already used another method by divide the navbar to 3 parts.. left part (3 menus), logo and right (another 3 menus)